# PnP Partner Pack 2.0 - Value cannot be null. Parameter name: certificate

Tags: pnp

I am setting up the PnP Partner Pack 2.0 but getting an error 'Value cannot be null. Parameter name: certificate'. I have followed the all steps and made sure to avoid below possible errors. Can you please guide me if I am missinng anything?

1. Reply URL with trailing slash "/"
2. Permissions to other applications(SharePoint Online and Azure Graph)
3. Certificate Keycredentials in manifest
4. Captured the Thumbprint using powershell
5. Client Id, Secret and Storage keys in web.config
6. Uncehcked the option "Enable Organizational Authentication" during the deployment
7. Certificate in Azure Web app and the WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES in app settings

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that in app settings of your Web App, the value of WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES is set to *****
2. Make sure that the App Service Plan of your Web App is at least Basic (not free)